# How to update a kivy label from another class

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rows = 2
        self.accel  = Label(text = "unknown")
        self.orein = Label(text = "unknown")
        self.add_widget(self.accel)
        self.add_widget(self.orein)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1)

    def update(self, dt):
        ac = "dfskjjlfh"
        ore = "kjdsfkjdf"
        App.accel.text = ac
        App.orein.text = ore

MyApp().run()
```

I am having trouble finding an answer, to how I can update a Label from an another class. I keep getting the following error:

```
The following code is unreachable
```

Both widgets are stuck with the string unknown, but do not change to the variables in the function update.

Comment: Please update actual error message. The code you posted will never throw the error you mentioned.

Comment: The code ran, but it never changed. But when using Pycharm and went through debug mode, i could see the following error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea about the error you mentioned :

> `The following code is unreachable`

May be the IDLE you are using causes the error (as your posted code will never throw such error).

However, there's indeed some issues with your code.

Firstly, in method `build` you did,

```py
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1)
```

As you `return` first then schedule a callback, your callback function will never be executed. So you need to switch their order.

Secondly, in method `update` you did `App.accel.text`. This will raise `AttributeError` as the `App` class has no such property `accel`. Moreover it's even not there in the instance of `App` class (i e. in `MyApp`). You generally need not to refer the `App` class directly, rather it's instance (except for some method like `get_running_app` etc.)

As it seems you want to access the property of `MyGrid` in `MyApp`, create an instance of that class in method `build` thereby you will be able to access whatever properties you defined in that class. Thus your modified `MyApp` should now look like,

```py
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.grid = MyGrid() # Creating an instance.
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.)
        return self.grid

    def update(self, dt):
        ac = "dfskjjlfh"
        ore = "kjdsfkjdf"
        # Now access that instance and its properties.
        self.grid.accel.text = ac
        self.grid.orein.text = ore
```